# Using WM_SETFOCUS and WM_KILLFOCUS

Tags: delphi, winapi

In Delphi, I have two edit boxes and a button.

Edit1 is selected by default. I want to change focus using messages. But if I do as below, it all gets messed up with selection ranges in both edits, caret in the wrong box etc.

The reason I'm using messages is so that I can control focus in an external application. This seems to work, up to a point but clearly, the windows internal state is a bit scrambled. I don't have the source for the external program.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(edit1.handle,WM_KILLFOCUS,0,0);
  PostMessage(edit2.handle,WM_SETFOCUS,0,0);
end;
```

... So can it be done? Am I missing a message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WM_SETFOCUS and WM_KILLFOCUS are both notification messages that Windows sends to window handles when they receive and lose input focus, respectively, and you should not post those yourself. Instead, simply call `SetFocus(edit2.handle)` or `edit2.SetFocus()` to set the focus.

If for some reason you can't do that synchronously from your button click handler, you can post a custom message to a local message handler in your own form and make the SetFocus call from that message handler.

Comment: I have the handle to a control I want to focus in a 3rd party application, so I need to send it messages if possible - I have no way to access the source for that application.

Comment: I'd read the documentation for SetFocus and it says it just sends those messages and selects the window. But I also see the comment ... "By using the AttachThreadInput function, a thread can attach its input processing to another thread. This allows a thread to call SetFocus to set the keyboard focus to a window attached to another thread's message queue." So I'm doing that now and it's working fine. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: `focusedThreadID := GetWindowThreadProcessID(wh, nil) ;
  if AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadID, focusedThreadID, true) then
  try
    Windows.SetFocus(h);
  finally
    AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadID, focusedThreadID, false) ;
  end;`