# Autohotkey: How to unfocus a control without focusing another (unfocus all controls)?

Tags: focus, autohotkey

I am writing an Autohotkey script that fiddles with some Photoshop windows and controls.

I need to be able to unfocus the currently focused control (say, Edit3), so that no control has focus after that (I could explain why exactly I need to do that if necessary, but it seems irrelevant, I just really need all controls unfocused).

AHK's [ControlFocus](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlFocus.htm) command doesn't provide such an option.

I tried using a [Windows Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like this:

```
SendMessage, 0x8, 0, 0, Edit3, A  ; WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x08
```

but it doesn't do anything.
In comparison, the opposite one works as expected and focuses the control:

```
SendMessage, 0x7, 0, 0, Edit3, A  ; WM_SETFOCUS = 0x07
```

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong with the WM_KILLFOCUS message?

Just to clarify: I don't want to simulate clicks, switch windows, add new invisible controls which to focus etc. I just want to know how to unfocus a control.

**So, any idea how to unfocus a control, without focusing another one?**

Comment: `SendMessage, 0x7` also doesn't alter the focus for me (tested in skype). Frankly, "Sent to a window after it has gained the keyboard focus" doesn't sound like a huge help in setting focus at all (also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469234/using-wm-setfocus-and-wm-killfocus ). Regarding your question: No, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
last_active_win:=winexist("A") ;get the previous windows process before launching your gui

Gui +AlwaysOnTop 

Gui Add, Button, x10 w100 h30 , % 1
 
Gui Show,, My GUI ;launch the gui which gets the focus 

sleep 500

WinActivate ahk_id %last_active_win% ;reactivate previous windows to unfocus controls from gui

return
```

Answer (score -1):

You can send #d and you will go to Desktop. Which is going to focus on the desktop but can work for you.

```
SendInput, #d
```